# bash: using find with multiple file types, provided as an array

Tags: bash, directory, filtering

In a bash function, I want to list all the files in a given folder which correspond to a given set of file types. In pseudo-code, I am imagining something like this:

```
getMatchingFiles() {
  output=$1
  directory=$2
  shift 2
  _types_=("$@")

  file_array=find $directory -type f where-name-matches-item-in-_types_

  # do other stuff with $file_array, such as trimming file names to
  # just the basename with no extension

  eval $output="${file_array[@]}"
}

dir=/path/to/folder
types=(ogg mp3)
getMatchingFiles result dir types
echo "${result[@]}"
```

---

For your amusement, here are the multiple workarounds, based on my current knowledge of bash, that I am using to achieve this. I have a problem with the way the function returns the array of files: the final command tries to execute each file, rather than to set the output parameter.

```
getMatchingFiles() {
  local _output=$1
  local _dir=$2
  shift 2
  local _type=("$@")
  local _files=($_dir/$_type/*)
  local -i ii=${#_files[@]}
  local -a _filetypes
  local _file _regex

  case $_type in
    audio )
      _filetypes=(ogg mp3)
      ;;
    images )
      _filetypes=(jpg png)
      ;;
  esac

  _regex="^.*\.("
  for _filetype in "${_filetypes[@]}"
  do
     _regex+=$_filetype"|"
  done

  _regex=${_regex:0:-1}
  _regex+=")$"

  for (( ; ii-- ; ))
  do
    _file=${_files[$ii]}
    if ! [[ $_file =~ $_regex ]];then
      unset _files[ii]
    fi
  done

  echo "${_files[@]}"

  # eval $_output="${_files[@]}" # tries to execute the files
}

dir=/path/to/parent
getMatchingFiles result $dir audio
echo "${result[@]}"
```

Comment: Why not just return the result from the function instead of passing by reference?

Comment: @Inian Could you explain how I would do that?

Comment: `file_array=find $directory -type f where-name-matches-item-in-_types_` will just assign the string to file array, nothing is being executed.

Comment: @JamesNewton: Did you try my suggestion below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update: namerefs can indeed be arrays** (see PesaThe's answer)

### Without spaces in file and directory names

I first assume you do not have spaces in your file and directory names. See the second part of this answer if you have spaces in your file and directory names.

In order to pass `result`, `dir` and `types` by name to your function, you need to use namerefs (`local -n` or `declare -n`, available only in recent versions of bash).

Another difficulty is to build the find command based on the types you passed but this is not a major one. Pattern substitutions can do this. All in all, something like this should do about what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

getMatchingFiles() {
    local -n output=$1
    local -n directory=$2
    local -n _types_=$3
    local filter

    filter="${_types_[@]/#/ -o -name *.}"
    filter="${filter# -o }"
    output=( $( find "$directory" -type f \( $filter \) ) )

    # do other stuff with $output, such as trimming file names to
    # just the basename with no extension
}

declare dir
declare -a types
declare -a result=()

dir=/path/to/folder
types=(ogg mp3)
getMatchingFiles result dir types
for f in "${result[@]}"; do echo "$f"; done
```

### With spaces in file and directory names (but not in file suffixes)

If you have spaces in your file and directory names, things are a bit more difficult because you must assign your array such that names are not split in words; one possibility to do this is to use `\0` as file names separator, instead of a space, thanks to the `-print0` option of `find` and the `-d $'\0'` option of `read`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

getMatchingFiles() {
    local -n output=$1
    local -n directory=$2
    local -n _types_=$3
    local filter

    filter="${_types_[@]/#/ -o -name *.}"
    filter="${filter# -o }"
    while read -d $'\0' file; do
        output+=( "$file" )
    done < <( find "$directory" -type f \( $filter \) -print0 )

    # do other stuff with $output, such as trimming file names to
    # just the basename with no extension
}

declare dir
declare -a types
declare -a result=()

dir=/path/to/folder
types=(ogg mp3)
getMatchingFiles result dir types[@]
for f in "${result[@]}"; do echo "$f"; done
```

### With spaces in file and directory names, even in file suffixes

Well, you deserve what happens to you... Still possible but left as an exercise.

Comment: Thanks! What exactly does `local -n <var>` do? I have tried googling for it, but the man pages I find don't mention an `-n` option. And is there any advantage in `+=` for setting `file_array`? Is a simple `=` not good?

Comment: `local -n directory=$1` declares `directory as a named reference to whatever `$1` is. So, in our example, when we call `getMatchingFiles dir ...`, after this declaration, the local `directory` variable and the global `dir` variable are the same. And you are right, in this case, `file_array=` would do the same. In modified my answer.

Comment: Why aren't you collecting content into an array?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I do (in the `file_array` array), but as the OP wanted to pass the array by name and I did not know that a *nameref* could also be an array  (thanks to PesaThe answer I learned something today), I had to return a value.

Comment: Namerefs wouldn't be very useful if they couldn't point to arrays -- that's the primary thing they do one *can't* easily do without 'em (barring `eval`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, thanks, nice to know. Up to now I was puzzled by the "*local: output: reference variable cannot be an array*" error message you get when you try to `declare -an var`. I got it now, even if I am still not 100% sure I understand this error message.

Comment: Well, you are trying to create a nameref (think of it as "link") to some other variable and make it an array at the same time. That does not make much sense, does it.

Comment: @PesaThe Agreed. Because of these variable declarations I probably started considering bash as a kind of strongly typed language, which it is not yet. A nameref is indeed a nameref on anything, no type checking here.

Answer (score 2):

As a matter of fact, it is possible to use `nameref` (note that you need `bash` 4.3 or later) to reference an array. If you want to put the output of `find` to an array specified by a name, you can reference it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

getMatchingFiles() {

   local -n output=$1
   local dir=$2
   shift 2
   local types=("$@")
   local ext file
   local -a find_ext

   [[ ${#types[@]} -eq 0 ]] && return 1

   for ext in "${types[@]}"; do
      find_ext+=(-o -name "*.${ext}")
   done

   unset 'find_ext[0]'
   output=()

   while IFS=  read -r -d $'\0' file; do
      output+=("$file") 
   done < <(find "$dir" -type f \( "${find_ext[@]}" \) -print0)
}

dir=/some/path

getMatchingFiles result "$dir" mp3 txt
printf '%s\n' "${result[@]}"

getMatchingFiles other_result /some/other/path txt
printf '%s\n' "${other_result[@]}"
```

---

Don't pass your variable `$dir` as a reference, pass it as a value instead. You will be able to pass a literal as well.

Comment: Interesting, I did not know that. Do you know then why declaring `local -na output=$1` raise the "*local: output: reference variable cannot be an array*" error?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet You don't reference the array per se. You reference the variable and any operation done on the ref will be actually done on the original. So, for example, referencing an element of an array will be done on the original variable. That's all there is to it.

Comment: Thanks, PesaThe, you made my day.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet, ...you might give this answer a +1, as I have, if you've learned from it.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Done, of course. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 0):

Supporting the original, unmodified calling convention, and correctly handling extensions with whitespace or glob characters:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

getMatchingFiles() {
  declare -g -a "$1=()"
  declare -n gMF_result="$1"  # variables are namespaced to avoid conflicts w/ targets
  declare -n gMF_dir="$2"
  declare -n gMF_types="$3"
  local gMF_args=( -false )   # empty type list not a special case
  local gMF_type gMF_item

  for gMF_type in "${gMF_types[@]}"; do
    gMF_args+=( -o -name "*.$gMF_type" )
  done

  while IFS= read -r -d '' gMF_item; do
    gMF_result+=( "$gMF_item" )
  done < <(find "$gMF_dir" '(' "${gMF_args[@]}" ')' -print0)
}

dir=/path/to/folder
types=(ogg mp3)
getMatchingFiles result dir types
```

Comment: Hm, is it really working for extensions with glob chars? `types=("t*xt")` will output even `.txt` or `.tsomethingxt` etc. In order to process extensions with globs literally (I think that is  what you wanted), you would have to escape them. Or maybe that was your intention?

Comment: PesaThe is right. Moreover, the `find` command is bogus: 1) the `-type f` is missing and 2) it outputs only the files with the last extension (`mp3` here) because `-name *.mp3 -print0` is interpreted as `-name *.mp3` **and** `-print0` while all other `-name *.xxx` are not anded with any action and do not produce anything.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Yep, `type -f` is just a detail but `\( \)` are really needed.